# How to create a program that creates a math problem

Tags: java

There's a great chance that I am way off (super beginner!) but, I'm trying to make a program that displays a value for m, x, and b and requires a user to input the value of y using the slope-intercept formula.

I'm not sure how to make the program create random questions and then evaluate whether or not the user's answer is correct.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlgebraTutor {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        public static void int solve_when_given_y(int m_value, int x_value, int b_value){
            Scanner input;
            input = new Scanner( System.in );

            System.out.println ("Given: ");

            Random rand = new Random();
            int high = 101; int low = -100;
            int m_value = rand.nextInt(high-low) + low;
            int x_value = rand.nextInt(high-low) + low;
            int b_value = rand.nextInt(high-low) + low;

            System.out.println ("m = " + m_value);
            System.out.println ("x = " + x_value);
            System.out.println ("b = " + b_value);

            int student_answer = input.nextInt();

            if (input.equals(answer)){
                System.out.println("Correct");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is "+ answer);
                }
        }
    }   

    int m_value = 0;
    int x_value = 0;
    int b_value = 0;

    public static double calculate_y(double m_value, double x_value, double b_value){
        double y_value = m_value * x_value + b_value;
        return y_value;
    }


}
```

Comment: `input` is the `Scanner` object. You want to be comparing `student_answer` with the answer (Your variable `answer` is never declared). And since they're primitives, use `==`. Also you can't have methods inside your main.

Comment: Should this be at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: @TimothyT. Code Review requires working code

Comment: In order to judge if the _student's_ answer is correct, your _program_ first has to "know", or at least be able to _compute_, the correct answer for itself...

Comment: You are fairly close to a correct solution.  Look at what you are comparing `student_answer` to.  Is that correct?

Comment: Oh ... and there is a major Java syntax error in your code.  You have declared a method **inside** another method.   The body of your `solve_when_given_y` method should actaully be the body of the `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced braces `main` and `solve_when_given_y`. So it's like declaring a method inside of another method   I assume

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class S1 {
    public static void solve_when_given_y(int m_value, int x_value, int b_value) {
        Scanner input;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Given: ");

        Random rand = new Random();
        int high = 101;
        int low = -100;
        m_value = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        x_value = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        b_value = rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        System.out.println("m = " + m_value);
        System.out.println("x = " + x_value);
        System.out.println("b = " + b_value);
        System.out.print("Your Answer ");
        double student_answer = input.nextInt();
        double calculated = calculate_y(m_value, x_value, b_value);
        if (student_answer == calculated) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, the answer is " + calculated);
        }
        input.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int m_value = 0;
        int x_value = 0;
        int b_value = 0;

        solve_when_given_y(m_value, x_value, b_value);

    }

    public static double calculate_y(double m_value, double x_value, double b_value) {
        double y_value = m_value * x_value + b_value;
        return y_value;
    }

}
```

I've modified based on many assumptions. Hope this helps

Comment: Well yea ... but 1) it is not a good solution and 2) doing a students homework for them doesn't help them to learn.   It is better to give them Hints and let them work it out for themselves.